Basement smoke alarm location -- ceiling protrusions vs stairwell protection?
So, in order to meet current requirements for an upcoming inspection, we're upgrading our smoke alarms to a set of battery-operated, wirelessly interconnected alarms (it's the best we can do given the circumstances).  The alarms outside and inside the bedrooms installed without much difficulty; however, the alarm for the basement poses a much larger issue.
The current alarm for the basement (a battery-operated single-station unit of rather unknown vintage) is on the ceiling of the basement stairs, near the top.  While this seems to me to be a good location from the perspective of detecting smoke, it's not practical to install another unit there because it'd require the installer to balance on the stairs, something we don't feel comfortable attempting.
Furthermore, putting it at the bottom of the basement stairs, as recommended by NFPA 72 29.11.3.4 point 10, would also be a challenge.  This is because the door to the furnace room is immediately to the left of the bottom of the stairs, and the ceiling of the rest of the basement, located to the right of the bottom of the stairs, has 10" protrusions dropping down from the 84" (7') ceiling.  The presence of these protrusions triggers NFPA 72 29.11.3.4 point 12, which refers the reader to NFPA 72 17.7.4.2.4.
Given that the basement ceiling itself is otherwise level, NFPA 72 17.7.4.2.4.1 applies to it.  Given that the 10" drop of the beams causes them to exceed the 10% ratio of beam depth to ceiling height used as a criteria in that paragraph, and that there are only two protrusions on the whole ceiling (one of which runs from near the stairs to the other end of the basement, with the other located well away from the bottom of the stairs), Point 2 is triggered as the spacing is well over the 40% of the ceiling height, resulting in an apparent requirement for alarms in the other two "bays" of the ceiling, even though that space, while semi-finished, is only lightly used.
Finally, the fact that the furnace room door is often left open (due to concerns about airflow to the furnace, even though the room is sizeable and a window to the outside) makes me concerned about false alarms, despite the fact that our new alarms comply with the UL 217, 8th Edition nuisance fire tests.
So, is my situation governed by the drop ceiling rules (17.7.4.2.4.1) or the basement stair rules (NFPA 72 29.11.3.4 point 10)?  Or is there another location I should be using instead?  See the diagram below for a general, not-to-scale layout of the situation.


I see no reason that putting a smoke alarm on the stairway ceiling would "require the installer to balance on the stairs..." There are many products that are designed to allow safe work from a ladder on stairs; here is an example which I have no affiliation with but I own one and am happy with it:  https://provisiontools.com/products/pivit-laddertool?srsltid=AfmBOoo6kLh4b_NoojlvXiquebWP_T7OnXp1zZQlSAq6nh4WjtVY9byV

A photo showing the actual location would be helpful...

@JimmyFix-it  Maybe OP has seen too many pictures online of why women live longer than men using ladders.
